# How to check for top level domain in Ruby string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'd like to be able to check if a user enters their name with any top level domain in the string. Preferably, validating this with a regex.

I'd like to still allow a user to put a `.` in their username so `Mr. Bobby` would be legitimate.

For example, `bobby` is fine, but `bobby.com` would be caught by the regex. Is there any way to do this for all TLD's?

Comment: What sort of input are you getting? A few more examples of valid and invalid input would help.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]" and the linked page. Your question isn't asked well. Show  the minimum code that demonstrates the problem you're having. Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is, unfortunately, yes, no and maybe all at once.

I've [written a gem](https://github.com/twg/domain_prefix) which attempts to do this by transforming the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat) into something that can be executed programmatically. For the most part it's pretty accurate but there are still some dark corners in that list not properly qualified. Top-level domains these days are pure anarchy and those that register them are free to organize them however they see fit, or not organize them at all.

Although today `bobby` is not a gTLD, it's possible that tomorrow it might become one. The [list of proposed domains at ICANN](https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/) is surreal to say the least and things such things as [`.google`](https://icannwiki.org/.google) have already been approved just to make life as confusing as possible.

So it depends on what you mean by "top level domain". Some things that are totally valid even if they seem completely wrong, like https://www.registry.google/

The [list of top-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) might seem thorough enough, but some of these organize their subdomains in a particular way which complicates the issue. For example, Australia does not allow direct `.au` domains, so `example.au` is not valid, however `example.com.au` is. The "Public Suffix" list is the compilation of these rules use for cookie-assignment purposes.

Before that list existed it was possible to assign a cookie that stuck to all of `.com.au`, a behaviour that was highly undesirable to say the least. It's worth noting that `com.au` is not a valid domain despite matching the usual `\w+\.\w\w+` pattern.

Comment: Ugh. I used to be in that world and dealing with the list, and ICANN and other registrars made me nuts.

Comment: @theTinMan Tell me about it. I'm dealing with email and I've given up on thinking we'll ever make sense of this. Is `x@y` a valid email? Could be! Only way to know for sure is to try and resolve it, or try and deliver it.